# Search a Node in all Element Levels in a XML File

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have some format versions of a XML file that i need to upload to a DB using C#. But I don´t now exactly what level the tags i need to import are, because, depending on the version of the xml the tag could be inner others groups or tags.

Some examples of XML files

```
Ex1)
<a>
   <group1>
      <tag>searched tag</tag>      
   </group1>
   <b>   </b>
   <c>   </c>
</a>

Ex2)
<a>
   <b>
      <group1>
          <c>
             <tag>searched tag</tag>
          </c>
      </group1>
   </b>
</a>
```

The searched tag will always inside the group1 tag, and all the files has xmlns and schema attributes.

I tried use the xml.SelectSingleNode(\group1\tag) but throw an error when the file has a schema header and namespace config.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure element `tag` is below `group1`, and there can be at any number of levels of intermediate nodes in between them, and assuming all elements are in global namespace then use : (Note the direction of slashes):

```
xml.SelectSingleNode("//group1//tag")
```

If however you *don't* know which `xmlns` the respective elements are in, then you will need to do like so:

```
xml.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='group1']//*[local-name()='tag']")
```

Note however that use of '//' for large files in the MSXml parser can be a bit slow, so it would be faster e.g. if you can isolate the exact paths to the respective nodes and then can use `|`

e.g. In your example, if the tag can be 'either' `Ex1` OR `Ex2`, then:

```
/a/group1/tag | /a/b/group1/c/tag
```

should work.

Comment: I´ve tried use the local-name tag like the answer but still got a empty XmlNode has a result. The only way I founded is to use the xml.GetElementsByTagName(childNodeName) passing the group1 name and search for the tag in the XMLNodeList received.

Comment: My bad - I had missed the `()` after `local-name()` - fixed - I've checked with a couple of test files using the MsXml.

Comment: Great! that works for the select the TAG value and to select all the group1 Element too...thanks